# Effect found for 2*2 ANOVA (univariate) but not for Repeated Measures ANOVA?

Tags: anova, repeated-measures

I have a 2*2 design, N=73, and I have pre and post measurements for a construct named 'social status norms'. The null hypothesis of equal variances was not rejected. I conducted a 2*2 ANOVA (my pre-measurement was used as one of four covariates) and I found a significant interaction (p = .036, partial η2 = .066).

However, when I ran a Repeated Measures ANOVA, no significant interaction was found (p = .131, partial η2 = .034).The same covariates were used for both analyses. I'm not sure why there is an effect for one, and not the other. The n for each group range from 16 to 32, so perhaps it is the small sample sizes? Or small partial η2 (.066)?